# Loop through Outlook emails with Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to make a javascript add-in for MS Outlook to loop through all new emails and parse them conditionally. I can't find anything on it though. How can I do this or do javascript add-ins only parse messages currently being read? If I can't do this with JS how can I do it? Could I use a Rest API or would I have to use VBA/VSTO? Hoping to make it cross OS compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anyone is looking for an answer to this as of 2017 its not possible. You have to use the Rest API if you want it to be cross OS compatible. This Rest API requires them to be using Microsoft Exchange Online as their host. I'm using it from an external server, but you could (as far as I know) use JS in an add-in to query the Rest API and process on interval or bootup to get emails.